# how to store matrices in heap memory

Tags: c

My code below works just fine. However, I want to know how I can store the matrices in heap memory. The code accepts 3 positive integers a, b and c from the user. User then input two matrices. First matrix is n(rows) by m(columns) and second matrix is m(rows) by p(columns).

the matrix product/output is n rows by p columns,e.g;
**Sample Input**

4

3

2

14 9 3

2 11 15

0 12 17

5 2 3

12 25
9 10

8 5

**Sample Output**

273 455

243 235

244 205

102 160

```
int main(void) {
    int row1, row2, col1, col2, i, j, e;
    int temp, **matrix1, **matrix2, **mtxProduct;

    scanf("%d", &row1);
    scanf("%d", &col1);

    temp = col1;
    row2=temp;    
    scanf("%d", &col2);

    if (col1 != row2) {
        printf("\nIncorrect combination!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    matrix1 = (int**) malloc(row1 * sizeof(int*));

    //read elements of 1st matrix
    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        matrix1[i] = (int*) malloc(col1 * sizeof (int));
        for (j = 0; j < col1; j++) {
            scanf("%d %d %d\n", &matrix1[i][j], &matrix1[i][j], &matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    matrix2 = (int**) malloc(row2 * sizeof (int*));

    //read elements of 2nd matrix
    for (i = 0; i < row2; i++) {
        matrix2[i] = (int*) malloc(col2 * sizeof (int));
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
            scanf("%d %d %d", &matrix2[i][j], &matrix2[i][j], &matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    mtxProduct = (int**) malloc(row1 * sizeof (int*));

    for (i = 0; i < col2; i++) {
        mtxProduct[i] = (int*) malloc(col2 * sizeof (int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
            mtxProduct[i][j] = 0;
            for (e = 0; e < row2; e++) {
                mtxProduct[i][j] +=(matrix1[i][e] * matrix2[e][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mtxProduct[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using dynamic allocation, which means - use `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modern C compiler, starting from C99, it should allow the following ideom

```
double (*A)[m] = malloc(sizeof(double[n][m]));
```

such a thing is call a "variably modified type" and carries along the necessary size so the compiler can resolve `A[i][j]` and things like that by itself.

If you are a purist you could even do:

```
double (*A)[n][m] = malloc(sizeof *A);
```

And carry around the `*` by yourself, something like `(*A)[i][j]`.

And don't forget to `free` the space at the end when you don't need it anymore, `free(A)` should do in both cases.

Comment: I have updated the code- not quite sure with reading the matrice elements though

Answer (score 0):

As other answerers have said, you need to use `malloc`. I am assuming the entries in your matrices can only be `int`

```
int * allocate_matrix(int m, int n) {
  /* Returns an allocated m x n matrix */
  return malloc(sizeof(int) * m * n);
}
```

To access the matrix, you need to decided whether you use column-major or row-major form. In column-major form (promoted by FORTRAN and most common in scientific programming), you store each column continuously and one after another. To access the entry at (2,3), you would take the pointer to the matrix, say `A`, and dereference it wrt `2*(number of columns) + 1`. So, for an m x n matrix, it would be `A[1+2*n]` - you take one off the row and column numbers to account for 0-indexing.

If you want to get into this kind of stuff - it's really cool, honest - Google BLAS.

Comment: I can't find a link to my old lecture notes on this. :(

Comment: I have updated the code- not quite sure with reading the matrice elements though